# Вопрос по верстке. Сайт на laravel

Tags: php, вёрстка, laravel, foreach, if

Доброго времени! Такой вопрос по верстке.

Сайт на laravel, через @foreach перебираются блоки статей на главной странице, отличаются блоки положением текста и картинки. И вот задача: предположим, есть один `<div class="first">`, а другой `<div class="second">`. Как можно реализовать условие через if? То есть, предположим i=1, это `<class="first">`, i=2, это `<class="second">`, ну и, естественно else - error. И в первый div попадает одна статья, во второй другая. Или не через i, а как-то в условии прописать css класс. Не совсем понимаю, какой в данном случае синтаксис будет.

Ещё подробнее постараюсь объяснить: Разница в классах - разница в отображении контекста. class="first" - первая статья: идет "текст - картинка", class="first" - вторая статья: "картинка - текст". Нужно вывести это всё через if :)

А главный вопрос, вообще реально через if прописывать css классы, возможна ли такая реализация?
За ранее, большое спасибо!!!

Comment: вопрос что сначала показывать картинку или текст для четных и нечетных блоков можно наверное и чисто средствами css решить?

Comment: Но мне нужно через условие, если такой класс, то в начале идёт  "текст - картинка", если другой класс, то "картинка - текст". и так далее, на странице 10 блоков. Можно как-то это реализовать и как?

Comment: это я понял. и говорю вам, что альтернативно, можно с помощью css вообще без этих классов  реализовать. в зависимости от сложности верстки, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить переменную-счётчик, и вычислять значение по модулю. Этот демо-пример, можно скопировать целиком в отдельный шаблон, и на его основе дописать ваш файл:

```
@php
    $css = ['first', 'second'];
    $array = range(1, 10);
    $i = 0;
@endphp

@foreach($array as $string)
    <div class="{{$css[$i++ % 2]}}">{{$string}}</div>
@endforeach
```

В результате в исходном коде вы увидите теги:

```
<div class="first">1</div>
<div class="second">2</div>
<div class="first">3</div>
<div class="second">4</div>
<div class="first">5</div>
<div class="second">6</div>
<div class="first">7</div>
<div class="second">8</div>
<div class="first">9</div>
<div class="second">10</div>
```

Comment: а нельзя ли просто написать `<div class="{{ $loop->index % 2 ? "first" : "second" }}">` ?

Comment: либо `$cls = ["first", "second"]` и `class="{{ $cls[$loop->index%2] }}">`

Comment: @teran благодарю :) С массивом стилей действительно компактней выглядит.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за столь развернутый ответ!!!)

Comment: @Armida если моё решение вам подходит, вы можете отметить его галкой :)

Comment: Эдуард, я нажала, но, как я поняла, это ничего не изменило, так как я новичок, что-то там с репутацией ((